# JS scope convention for third (and greater) nested scopes

Tags: javascript

If you need to keep scope in a nested function, it is convention to make a variable that that is the the this like so: `var that = this;` and reference `that` in the nested function.   What is the convention name for the 3rd degree and beyond?

I have also come across a few situations where proxy is used, but have never had to pass nested proxy in JQuery.  Is there anything special for nested `proxy`s

Regular scope issue came up in backbone, with a potential (we are still working through it) to have to go another level down:

```
keyPressed: function(keyEvent) {
if(case1 && case2 && case3) {
  if(anotherCase) {
    .....
  }
  else if(yetAnotherCase) {
    ....
    var that = this;
    window.waitIntervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
      if(that.waitCount == 2) {
        that.isWaiting = false;
        that.waitCount = 0;

        that.mainCounter = 0;
        that.isRecording = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < that.signature; i++) {
          that.beatArray[i] = 0;
        }
        window.tapIntervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
          that.count = that.mainCounter + 1;              
          that.mainCounterTime = new Date().getTime();
          that.mainCounter = (that.mainCounter + 1) % that.signature;
        }, that.average);
        that.isTapping = false;
        that.countIn = 1;
        var bpm = 1000 / that.average * 60;
        that.set('tempo', bpm);
        window.clearInterval(waitIntervalID);
      }
      that.waitCount++;
    }, this.average);
    this.countIn++;
  }
}
},
```

Proxy scope :

```
    // add click handler to this beat
    $('#beat'+this.model.cid).click($.proxy(this.toggle, this));
    return this;
```

Comment: Could you provide an example showing why/how you want to change the variable name in different scopes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using a specific variable name for the item you are dealing with, instead of generic names like `that` or `self` or `me`. Then it should be obvious what name to use.

For example, if `this` is a DOM element, you might use:

```
var element = this;
```

If `this` is a `Cat` object (which comes to mind because I see a cat in the ad on this page), you could use:

```
var cat = this;
```

etc.

Of course if you're dealing with even more specific elements, or cats, or whatever, you could use more specific names than that. If I have a function that deals with a single generic DOM element I might call the variable `element`, but if, say, it deals with a `<ul>` and a `<li>` I might use `ul` and `li` for the respective variable names. Or whatever names make sense in the code.

Also, avoid using `this` entirely when you can. Much of the use of `this` in typical jQuery code comes from functions like `$.each()` and `$().each()`, e.g.

```
$('.foobar').each( function() {
    var element = this;
    $(element).on( 'click', function() {
        alert( 'Clicked = ' + element.id );
    });
});
```

It's much better to use named parameters with `.each()` instead:

```
$('.foobar').each( function( i, element ) {
    $(element).on( 'click', function() {
        alert( 'Clicked = ' + element.id );
    });
});
```

Regarding your question about using `nestedCat` in a nested function, I definitely wouldn't use variable names that refer to the *code structure*. Instead, the names should refer to the things you're talking about.

What is a nested cat anyway? I imagine this must be a kitten, so now we have something we can talk about:

```
function Cat( args ) {
    this.sex = args.sex;
    this.name = args.name;
    this.kittens = args.kittens;
}

var mommyCat = new Cat({
    sex:'F',
    name: 'Mommy Cat',
    kittens: [
        new Cat({ sex: 'M', name: 'Tom Kitty' }),
        new Cat({ sex: 'F', name: 'Cute Kitty' })
    ]
});
console.log( mommyCat );
mommyCat.kittens.forEach( function( kitten ) {
    console.log( kitten );
});
```

That logs:

```
Cat {sex: "F", name: "Mommy Cat", kittens: Array[2]}
Cat {sex: "M", name: "Tom Kitty", kittens: undefined}
Cat {sex: "F", name: "Cute Kitty", kittens: undefined}
```

Comment: and do you just call it `nestedCat` in the lower nested areas?